# (Automatically) migrate CodePlex project to GitHub

Tags: .net, github, version-control, migration, codeplex

I'm thinking about migrating my projects from CodePlex to GitHub.

**What is the best way to migrate everything (wiki, issues, etc.) from CodePlex to GitHub?**

Does someone know a tool to do that?

The most time consuming part would be the migration of all the wiki pages and add a link to their new home.

Comment: Am I right, that you have migrated your code without any problems?

Comment: The problem is not the code (it's git). It's all the wiki pages, issues, etc... Is there a tool which can do that? (In my case it's mostly the wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be existing tool for automating the process of:

- exporting Codeplex issue (an [API is in demand since 2010](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/25486)), even though the import to GitHub could be automated with the [GitHub issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)
- export Codeplex wiki page, even though the import would be as simple as adding text file in a Git repo, since a [GitHub wiki is in a Git repo](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/).
  Plus the format of Codeplex wiki markup isn't exactly a standard one, as illustrated by their [Wiki Markup Guide - Links & Files](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wiki%20Links&referringTitle=Wiki%20Formatting) section.
  Some conversion is needed, in order to match the [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/)).